# How to display increment raw data using iloc() depending on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm in the early stages of learning Python and am stumped on a topic of displaying raw data from a data frame depending on user input. I ask 'Would you like to see more data?' Yes displays first 5 rows. The question comes up again and if the user says Yes then the next 5 rows are displayed. This continues until user says No.
So far this is what i have. I can display the initial 5 rows but rows don't increase the second time, any help would be most appreciated. Thank you.

```
def more_data(df):
    st = 0
    sp = 5
    more_data = input('\nWould you like to see more data? Enter yes or no.\n')
    while more_data.lower() == 'yes':
        df = df.iloc[st:sp]
        print(df)
        st += 5
        sp += 5
        more_data = input('\nWould you like to see moreeeeee data? Enter yes or   no.\n')
        print(df)

def main():
    while True:
        more_data(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep on overwriting `df` so are unable to access the *next* 5 rows at any point. Assign your slice to another variable, e.g. `df_slice` below:

```
def more_data(df):
    st = 0
    more_data = input('\nWould you like to see more data? Enter yes or no.\n')
    while more_data.lower() == 'yes':
        df_slice = df.iloc[st: st+5]
        print(df_slice)
        st += 5
        more_data = input('\nWould you like to see moreeeeee data? Enter yes or   no.\n')

def main():
    while True:
        more_data(df)
```